# Problem in Apache CXF (Simple Frontend): 'Already connected'

Tags: java, web-services, spring, soap, cxf

I am using apache CXF for the first time. I am trying to establish a connection based on the CXF [simple front end](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/simple-frontend.html) ([Configuration notes](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/simple-frontend-configuration.html)) technology. I can't really see what I've done wrong, but I am getting a weird error (see below). I have also posted this question to users@cxf.apache.org, but I haven't received a response yet. Perhaps someone here can help.

The service bean that is wrapped here is a Spring / JPA service that does not know anything about the web, I want to use simple frontend to publish it as a web service without having to annotate it with Jax-ws etc. (This works in theory). Here's my configuration:

**Server:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:simple="http://cxf.apache.org/simple"
xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:cs="http://[www.mycompany.com]/coupon/service"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/simple http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/simple.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byType"
    >

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http.xml" /> 
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http-binding.xml" /> 
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

<!—my service implementation -->
<import resource="classpath*:persistenceContext.xml" /> 

<!--  serviceClass points to an interface -->
<simple:server id="server" serviceBean="couponService"
    serviceClass="[com.mycompany].MyServiceInterface"
    bindingId="http://apache.org/cxf/binding/http"
    address="/${wsdl.path}"
    serviceName="cs:couponService"
    endpointName="cs:couponServicePort"
    >
    <simple:dataBinding>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding" />
    </simple:dataBinding>
    <simple:binding>
        <soap:soapBinding version="1.2" mtomEnabled="true" />
    </simple:binding>
</simple:server>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:service.properties" />
</beans>
```

**Client:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:simple="http://cxf.apache.org/simple"
xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:oxm=http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
xmlns:cs="http://[www.mycompany.com]/coupon/service"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/simple http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/simple.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byType"
    >


<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http.xml" /> 
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http-binding.xml" /> 
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />


<simple:client id="couponService" wsdlLocation="${wsdl.url}?wsdl"
    serviceName="cs:couponService"
    endpointName="cs:couponServicePort"
    transportId="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
    address="${wsdl.url}"
    bindingId="http://apache.org/cxf/binding/http"
    serviceClass="[com.mycompany].MyServiceInterface">
    <simple:dataBinding>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding" />
    </simple:dataBinding>
    <simple:binding>
        <soap:soapBinding mtomEnabled="true" version="1.2" />
    </simple:binding>
</simple:client>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:service.properties" />
```

On the client side, I inject the generated service into my web application (I am using wicket but that should be irrelevant) and when I call service methods on it I get an IllegalStateException from java.net.HttpURLConnection saying the connection is already open. Here’s the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: IllegalStateException invoking http://localhost:9999/services/coupon: Already connected
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:2058)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:2048)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:639)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.http.interceptor.DatabindingOutSetupInterceptor.handleMessage(DatabindingOutSetupInterceptor.java:91)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:487)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:313)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:265)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:68)
at $Proxy30.createIndividualUserCouponsJob(Unknown Source)
at [com.mycompany].coupons.web.app.dummycontent.DummyContentInitializer.addSomeIndividualCoupons(DummyContentInitializer.java:84)
at [com.mycompany].coupons.web.app.dummycontent.DummyContentInitializer.addSomeCoupons(DummyContentInitializer.java:68)
at [com.mycompany].coupons.web.app.dummycontent.DummyContentInitializer.init(DummyContentInitializer.java:50)
at org.apache.wicket.Application.callInitializers(Application.java:843)
at org.apache.wicket.Application.initializeComponents(Application.java:678)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:725)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.init(WicketServlet.java:219)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:433)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:617)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:220)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
at [com.mycompany].coupons.web.test.Start.main(Start.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(HttpURLConnection.java:103)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.thresholdNotReached(HTTPConduit.java:1889)
at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.close(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:99)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1980)
```

This happens the first time a service call is made, and the only URLConnection that is opened before that is that of the wsdl.

I have searched the web for similar problems, but all I found was a bug using rest that has already been fixed. I am trying to use the simple frontend, as my service is not annotated with jax-ws annotations and I would like to keep it that way.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself: I need to turn chunking off in the http conduit (I don't really understand a word of this :-)). Anyway, it works like this:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client AllowChunking="false" />
</http-conf:conduit>
```